# Windows Store 8.1 and System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Recently, I tried to make a battery app (C#, store app) for Windows 8.1
(I am using VS2013, tried also VS2012 with the same result).
As it turned out, I need to add a Reference to the project - but I cannot add anything in Reference Manager: it says "All of the Framework assemblies are already referenced". And all what I need is to get System.Windows.Forms - when I search for it, nothing appears.

Any ideas, what can I do?
(Please tell me if I forgot something essential)

Comment: Windows store apps are Silverlight, not WF.

Comment: Actually, 8.1 isn't necessarily Silverlight either, could be Store/Phone XAML or Store/Universal XAML

Comment: @duobix Maybe re-phrasing the question to ask how to do something in a Windows Phone app that was previously available in WinForms would get the answer you want.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Store Apps are build, from scratch, on new technology stack , So Windows Form and WPF are not part of Windows Store apps.

- Windows store apps and Windows Forms apps has there different set of
  APIs.
- Windows store apps are used to known as known as Metro apps and Right now they have been merging the stuff(don't want to go into the details).

[This will give a basic knowledge about this new Technology](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/11/20/building-windows-store-apps-with-net.aspx)

So, above are the just a small hints about the differences. Actually, It is not possible to explain all the stuff here. Just explore.

Comment: FYI, Microsoft has dropped the use of "Metro" with the release of Windows 8. They're now referred to as "Universal" apps.

Comment: @Cameron Thanks, I just wanted to avoid the details somehow.