# Project targeting .NET Framework version 4.5.1 to Universal Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, win-universal-app

I'm a beginner and I developed a working project in C# using Visual Studio. I targeted the project for .NET Framework version 4.5.1 and it works fine. Since it is written in C# I would like to extend it in order to make it work on every Windows device

The problem I'm facing is the following. In my original project I had:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Media; // for playing sounds
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

and they gave no problems. If I put the same lines in the Windows Universal Platform version when I build the new solution I have for example [I'll put just two errors among the many ones]:

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Drawing' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  TestProgram C:\Users\Antonino\documents\visual studio2015\Projects\TestProgram\TestProgram\MainPage.xaml.cs 6

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ToolStripMenuItem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) TestProgram C:\Users\Antonino\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestProgram\TestProgram\MainPage.xaml.cs    80

Is there a smart way to have these missing files recognized in a simple way even when developing the universal Windows app? please don't tell me that I have to rewrite the whole project

Thanks in advance to those who will try to help,
Antonino

Comment: check this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/07/30/universal-windows-apps-in-net.aspx

Comment: @w.b thanks a lot for the help but maybe for my reduced experience I could not find anything to practically start a fix for the problem... which part of the link are you specifically referring to? thanks again!

Comment: I think you will have to rewrite the project as Universal Apps are based on a different technology, check also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544203/windows-store-8-1-and-system-windows-forms

Comment: @w.b I started reading the article and unfortunately it refers to Windows8 world... let's see if somebody has more recent details, I read that Microsoft has changed lots of things in the meanwhile... ciao!

Comment: You have to rewrite the whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue here isn't the framework version but rather the reduced framework API that is available to Universal Apps. Windows Universal apps don't have the same coverage of namespaces, classes, and APIs as the full .NET framework, and as a result, you can't reuse everything from full .net (such as System.Drawing) in a Universal Project.

However, you don't necessarily have to rewrite the WHOLE THING. instead, what you want to do is abstract the platform-specific behavior to an interface, and only that part has to be rewritten.

in otherwords, the global behaviors, UI and interaction can be reused using the classes available in all frameworks, usually represented by a Portable Class Library (PCL), and each version of your app (Winforms, Universal, Xamarin, etc) would reuse that shared library for the "core" of the application and the UI (and platform-specific behavior) would be the only part you would implement separately, in each version of the app you want to support.

I'm not sure if this answers your question entirely, but I do hope this was helpful.

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer, I'm really interested in understanding all the theory behind the failure so if you think you can edit your answer adding important details do it. On the other side, from a practical point of view, if I understood your idea you are suggesting me to put a layer between the two frameworks for translating the core functions between the two, rewriting just the UI in the new framework, right? thanks a lot again for your time!

Comment: essentially what it boils down to is the fact that the .net framework for Windows Universal Apps is smaller than the full .NET framework. so some things just are not available, and those are the parts you have to port over (rewrite), using the classes that ARE present. if you can add code samples for what you're trying to do perhaps we can help guide you in the right direction to do it on the universal platform. good luck!

Comment: the code is a very long project, I'll try to fix it and see what happens. Thank you very much, really! for the help and the explanations! hope to see you soon!